# Enable PHP short open tags via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-shorttags

I’m currently running through a tutorial for a CMS system which unfortunately uses short open tags.

I’ve confirmed that my host will not allow these in their PHP config, but that they run PHP in Apache mode (as opposed to CGI). To the best of my knowledge, this should then allow me to set the `short_open_tag` flag to `on` in an .htaccess file.

However, this appears to not be working. In the root directory, I've created an .htaccess file with just the following line, but the short open tags are still being ignored.

`php_flag short_open_tag on`

Am I doing something wrong? If not, can anyone suggest why it may not be working? Thanks.

**Note:** Someone has marked this question as being answered somewhere else. Not only does the question identified not have an accepted answer, it's based around and PHP config running in CGI mode, not Apache mode.

Comment: If you're just coding with the help of a tutorial, just write `<?php` instead when they use `<?` - or are you simply copy and pasting the whole tutorial?

Comment: I think you should try `php_value short_open_tag 1` in .htaccess file

Comment: I think you can do it in by `php_value short_open_tag 1`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - The tutorial came with a set of files, so replacing the short tags in sadly not an option.

Comment: You should try `php_admin_flag short_open_tag 1` but this can also be disabled by your provider. You should try the tutorial on a localhost with your own configuration.

Comment: @LeonStafford - You'll notice that not only does the question you pointed out not have an accepted answer, it seems that the OP had a PHP config set to CGI mode, not Apache. Therefore it is sadly not of help to me.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Thanks for the suggestion, but `php_admin_flag short_open_tag 1` produces an `Internal Server Error`. Thanks.

Comment: @DharmeshPatel and @Lan - Thanks, changing `php_flag` to `php_value` worked.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try this

```
 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value short_open_tag 1
 </IfModule>
```

This would solve the problem

Comment: Yes, I believe most of the host providers allow to override the php configuration.

Comment: Technically, you should be using `php_flag` instead of `php_value`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php.

Answer (score 6):

For `.htaccess` it should be `php_value short_open_tag 1`
For an ini file it's `short_open_tag=On`.

If it doesn't work in the `.htaccess` then you could try to add you own `php.ini` in you site root. That said it's unlikely to work.

Simply put the server admin could have completely disabled this functionality and no matter what you add you will not be able to activate it. It's best you ask your host and save yourself the pain.