# PHP update profile works fine on local host when hosted on server stop works

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have my PHP code working on my localhost perfectly fine but once i have uploaded the page to a server it comes out differently, can anyone suggest whats the problem

I shouldn't be getting the fields with this bit of code in it:`<?=$firstname?>`

here is the link to the page I am talking about:

[http://studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/k1003140/user1.php]

Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("location: user1.php"+$u);
} else {
    header ("location: index.php");
}
// see if the form has been completed
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
// Initialize any variables that the page might echo
$u = "";
$firstname = "";
$surname = "";
$gender = "Male";
$country = "";
$weight = "";
$height = "";

if(isset($_GET["u"])){
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

// check if the user exists in the database
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $surname = $row["surname"];
    $weight = $row["weight"];
    $height = $row["height"];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $gender = $row ["gender"];
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    mysql_connect ("studentnet","k1003140","k1003140"); mysql_select_db('db_k1003140');     
    // check if that user exist 
    $exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "'") or die ("query cant connect");   
    if (mysql_num_rows ($exists) != 0) {
    // update the description in the database       
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET firstname='$firstname', surname='$surname', weight='$weight', height='$height' WHERE firstname='$firstname'") or die ("update could not be applied");
            echo "successful";
    } else echo "the name does not exist";  
}
?>
```

Here is the PHP of my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>update MySql form</title>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div id="pageMiddle">  

            <form action="user1.php" method="POST">
                <div>
                <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?=$firstname?>"></p>
                <p>Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="<?=$surname?>"></p>   
                <p>Weight: <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" value="<?=$weight?>"></p>
                <p>Height: <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="<?=$height?>"></p>
                <p> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Description"></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone suggest how i can make user to edit their detail with $u not firstname because if anyone has the same name will be changing the other users detail, also is this safe or can anyone update anyone's detail.

Comment: There may be a higher php version that deprecates mysql extension in favor of using PDO. (mysql is deprecated as of version >= 5.5.0).
Also, please add in top of your file error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Please update your post then with errors that appeared.

Comment: No errors just it should be printing firstname of the logged in user rather than the syntax @VinodVT

Comment: I added the code you stated then I am gettin an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function display_errors() in /home/k1003140/www/user1.php on line 7` @ValentinRusk

Comment: yeah, my bad. ;-) check it again

Comment: Now I am getting a much longer error `Notice: Undefined variable: u in /home/k1003140/www/user1.php on line 10 Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/k1003140/www/php_includes/check_login_status.php on line 2
` but this makes sense @ValentinRusk

Comment: ok, this happens due to blank $u variable definition after inclusion of file.

Comment: I don't know how I can fix it, as I moved the $u variable the error stopped but still got the same result. @ValentinRusk

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I shouldn't be getting the fields with this bit of code in it:<?=$firstname?>" You need to explain the issue a bit more clearly. What is happening now, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: The link is above to visit the page to get a clear idea on what i am talking about, in the current form field i should be getting the logged in users information such as first name etc.. but the <?=$firstname?> apears rather than the users actual first name that code is meant to access the database and get the users name @Anigel

Comment: @user3311898 for future reference, it is much better for both you and future site visitors if your question is self explanatory and complete here on Stack Overflow rather than relying on people visiting a remote site that no longer displays the error. That will not help any users in future that have the same problem.

Comment: always use <?php ?> rather than <? ?> and <?php echo $x;?> rather than <?=$x;?>.
Short tags going deprecated later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before [PHP 5.4](https://www.php.net/echo) The short syntax operator for printing

```
<?= $var ?>
```

required short_open_tag to be turned on in the php.ini

The issue is most likely because you have short_open_tag enabled (or a newer version of php on your test server than on your live one.

If you edit your php.ini and make sure it is set to

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Then restart your webserver this should solve your problem

If you are not able to edit the php.ini then it is also possible to set [short_open_tag via the .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956857/enable-php-short-open-tags-via-htaccess)

Comment: Is there another way to write that tag as I have no access to the php.ini

Comment: You can set it via .htaccess files if your host allows that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956857/enable-php-short-open-tags-via-htaccess

Comment: Thanks I just used echo to print out the variable there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to make sure what version of PHP is running on the server compared to your local development computer as well as any modules that are compiled into your local PHP as this is the most common cause of things working in development and not in production.

Once you have confirmed the PHP versions, maybe try enabling errors to see just what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the variable `<? =$firstname?>` to an alternative `echo $firstname`