# Having trouble between PHP and jQuery GET

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, content-type

I am trying to send two variables from an HTML page to a PHP script but the response keeps coming back as text/html. aka, the entire code in the PHP file is being returned to the console.

My jQuery code:

```
    $.get(                             //call the server
            "biography_query.php",                //At this url
            {
                field: "value",
                id: decodeURIComponent(id),
                name: decodeURIComponent(name)
            }                          //And send this data to it
        ).done(                         //And when it's done
            function(data)
            {    
                console.log(data);
            },"jsonp"
        );
```

PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//start session on server to store the users information
session_start();

// establish connection to SQL database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","capstone") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];

// build statement to query database and return all characters
$SQL = "SELECT real_name, alternate_identities, aliases, nicknames, place_of_birth, first_appearance FROM `character` WHERE id='$id' AND superhero_name='$name'";

// execute the statement
$sqlReturn = mysqli_query($con, $SQL);

$row = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlReturn)) {
    $row['real_name'] = $r['real_name'];
    $row['alternate_identities'] = $r['alternate_identities'];
    $row['aliases'] = $r['aliases'];
    $row['nicknames'] = $r['nicknames'];
    $row['place_of_birth'] = $r['place_of_birth'];
    $row['first_appearance'] = $r['first_appearance'];
}
    echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Are you initializing the php with <?php or <? tags?

Comment: Are you testing on a web-server that has php installed or are you testing on a file on the local file system like `file:///path/to/file.php`? The last one will have this effect and if you have a web-server and php installed on your local system, you should use something like `http://localhost/path/to/file.php` instead.

Comment: I am currently using a WAMP server that has the ability to execute the PHP. I have made similar requests that work in the past but for some reason I cannot get this to work.

Comment: *`I am using <? tags`* - Are short tags enabled? If not, do or change `<?` to `<?php`. That could be a contributing factor.

Comment: @Fred-ii-That solved it! Thanks! I feel like an idiot :/

Comment: @arcadeRob Cool, glad it worked out. `Another happy ending`.

Comment: @arcadeRob If you want the question to be closed, I can make it an answer, or you can just delete the question. Either way, the choice is yours Rob. What matters is that the problem was solved, *cheers*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Answer the question and I'll mark it as answered. It may help somebody in the future. :)

Comment: @arcadeRob It has been done, plus I've added some extra information to my answer to give it a bit of **meat** to it, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I am using `<?` tags"*

*As per OP's wishes:* (to close the question, and for future readers)

If [**short open tags**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) are not enabled, you will need to either enable them, or change `<?` to `<?php`.

Here are a few articles on the subject, on Stack:

- [**How to enable PHP short tags?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185320/)
- [**Enable PHP short open tags via .htaccess**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18956857/)

On PHP.net:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php**