# PHP 7.2.14 "short_open_tag = On" ignored

Tags: php

On a fresh install of Fedora 28 running PHP 7.2.14 I am experiencing a strange issue where `short_open_tag = On` in the main php.ini is being ignored.  I have verified that there is only one instance of the flag in only the main php.ini (/etc/php.ini).  I have tried setting the flag on in .htaccess with `php_value short_open_tag 1`.  I have restarted Apache after each change.  But when I verify with phpinfo() the flag is always set to Off.  Has this flag been finally deprecated and the change is simply not reflected in the PHP change log (http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php)?  Looking through the PHP source (which I am no expert at) does not suggest an override so I am at a loss for explanation.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo()` for any other configuration files loaded

Comment: @Phil I looked through them all and double checked just now finding no occurrences aside from /etc/php.ini per phpinfo() output.  I also did a widespread search through the entire file system with no other results.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Double-check the `php.ini` file that `phpinfo()` reports. Is it the one you're making changes to? Sometimes there's separate config files for CLI and web

Comment: @Phil yes.  phpinfo() reports `Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini` along with a long list of `Additional .ini files parsed` all having been searched through with only `/etc/php.ini` yielding results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will first note that this question looks like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags). On the off chance it's not, here's my best answer.

The PHP documentation has a [page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) on the opening tags which says:

> PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

Check `phpinfo()` and you may see a section entitled **Configure Command** which contains compilation options. See if there's an `--enable-short-tags` option in there anywhere. If not, listen to @phil and look for a section titled **Additional .ini files parsed** which may list other ini files that have been parsed.

If your search is as thorough as you suggest in your original post and you still cannot get short tags, it may be turned off in an apache configuration file or the `short_open_tag` directive may exist in more than one spot. A PHP.ini directive will override any prior values that might have been set.

A grep search might help. In my PHP info output, I see these values:

> **Loaded Configuration File** - /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
>
> **Scan this dir for additional .ini files** - /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d

I can easily search all files in that location with this grep command:

`grep -ir 'short_open_tag' /etc/php5/apache2`

If you double/triple check all these ini files and restart apache and still can't get short_open_tag setting to work, this value may be set as an apache option. I suggest searching the apache configuration files for any reference to `short_open_tag`. The exact directory location may be different on your machine, but this grep command works for me

`grep -ir 'short_open_tag' /etc/apache2`

You should also keep in mind that your apache configuration may not be set up to even bother with .htaccess files so your attempt to override using .htaccess may be for naught unless you configure apache to actually use the .htaccess file. Assuming your apache configuration does bother parsing your htaccess file, this appears to be covered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956857/enable-php-short-open-tags-via-htaccess) here on SO.

And finally, if your server is configured to use PHP-FPM, then it uses a pool of PHP processes to handle PHP requests from the web server. If that's the case, you would need to restart php-fpm with this command:

`sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

**NOTE:** this command may vary on different machines.

Comment: Don't forget about [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) files too

Comment: @psyjoniz ah, would have been easier if you mentioned php-fpm up front.

Comment: @phil you monster!

Comment: @Phil Apologies, I was unaware it was playing a part.  I appreciate the help very much.  Cheers.

Comment: I gotta stop assuming Apache + PHP === mod_php

Comment: @psyjoniz if you wouldn't mind, please choose my answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkmark -- I'm trying to burnish my coding credentials in anticipation of the end of my current project. Sure could use the points. 